# How to detect if the UIMotionEffect is supported?

Tags: ios7, ios8, iphone-4

Is there a way to detect if the `UIMotionEffect` is supported on the device my app is running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test it like this :

```
if ([UIMotionEffect class]) {
    // do stuff with UIMotionEffect
} else {
    // UIMotionEffect does not exists
}
```

In iOS < 4.2 do it like this :

```
Class theClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIMotionEffect");
if (theClass) {
    // do stuff with UIMotionEffect
} else {
    // UIMotionEffect does not exists
}
```